res.cookie of cookie-parser not functioning correctly
Hey there I have set a cookie using cookie-parser npm package to set it.
 res.cookie("__Secure-AdminPortal", jwtToken, {
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "strict",
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000), // < 1d
      domain: ".sjj2NX.abc.mydomain.con", // my frontend subdomain
    });

Now I have two issues here:
ISSUE 1: If I do this, then somehow webpage frontend gets CORS error, but if I remove that domain parameter it works fine and there is no CORS error.
ISSUE 2: If i don't set the domain parameter in above code then frontend in Applications Tab > Cookie, here it sets the domain in cookie as my public backend API domain jaien-api-abc.mydomain.com This shouldn't have happened. Instead there should have the frontend domain being set
How do i remediate this , I have dig enough but couldn't found a solution or know why it is happening here.


I don't see how the presence of a Domain attribute would cause a CORS error. 2. Browsers silently reject attempts by jaien-api-abc.mydomain.com to set a cookie with a Domain attribute of value sjj2NX.abc.mydomain.com. Only the exact domain (jaien-api-abc.mydomain.com) or a parent domain that is not a public suffix are allowed (for example, mydomain.com is fine, but com isn't).


@jub0bs specific to nodejs cookie-parser, can we set the domain attribute in the code itself ? I couldn't find that in official documentation , But i have seen people use it in their codebase,i have read medium article where they added domain attribute.
